# Transfer zip file to web server

Tags: zip, httpclient, data-transfer

I would like to develop an app that targets everything from Gingerbread(version 2.3 API 9) to JellyBean(version 4.3 API 18).

The problem:
I need to transfer large images(40 to 50 at a time) either independently or in a zip file without the user having to click on each file being transferred. As far as I can tell I need to use the HttpClient(org.apache) that was deprecated after JellyBean.

Right now the application takes the images and zips them to a zip file prior to uploading. I can create additional zip files, for example if I have 50MB to transfer I can make each zip file about 10MB and have 5 files to be transferred if I have to. I need to transfer these files to a web server. I cant seem to find anything about transferring files after Jellybean. All the searching I've done uses the deprecated commands and the posts are 2-5 years old. I have installed andftp and transferred a 16MB zip file last night that was created by my app, but I really don't want to use that as it will require additional steps from the user. I will try andftp today and setup an intent to transfer the files to see how that works out. Supposedly andftp works until Lollipop(5.0). If there is an easier way please let me know, hopefully I've missed something about transferring files. Is there another way to do this after JellyBean?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v4EDq6mr  #57 has REST code for parse.com ( you can POST to any URL ) and the code uses the apache poolConnections example here : https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java   So, get a pool of like 6 Conns to where you want to POST images to and just keep uploading them. It will saturate your available network bandwidth and should not tax your server at all

Comment: I ended up using AndFTP and it worked out better than I thought. Need to get this to work on Lollipop and Marshmallow next.